# Cookies and session in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, session-cookies

I am wanting to control user sessions for a user login with `Remember me` checked, and a login without `Remember me` checked. if a user is logged in with `Remember me` checked then user doesn't need to login again after browser is closed or server is restarted unless the user is logged out. In case of login without `Remember me` not checked i want to save the users session which will be destroyed if browser is closed or server restarted.

Comment: You can use the `passport` package that will take care of most of that things for you automatically. Just keep in mind that keeping an user login after server restart can be hard to implement as you will need to store their session tokens in a persistent storage, instead as just keeping them in RAM, which fades away upon application restart

Comment: cant i save the session as cookie and retrieve it after server restart ?

Comment: What will you store on the cookie? If you store the session key, the server has to know how to revert that session key to the user it belongs. Usually, this information is not persistent stored. So, if you reset the server, it can no longer associate the key with any client, and will assume that it is invalid. Resulting in requiring the user to get a new token, which is done by requesting username/password again.

Comment: Session scopes exist for the duration of a sessions (when a user enters and leaves your site). Once the user leaves your site, the session is destroyed. You need a scope that persists (ie doesn't get destroyed) beyond the session. To implement this you need a token that has a time-to-live of whatever you want that to be, in this case, forever. You would store an encrypted version of the token in a cookie, and when the user visits your site, you would send that token to your server to see if it belongs to a user. If it does, and the token is valid, you log that user in.

Comment: as @Bruno says, you need to store this token in a database somewhere. In your case, I would just put it in the user table.